# CommonLibrary.NET repository and EF 4 working together?

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, repository, repository-pattern

I would like to use [CommonLibrary](http://commonlibrarynet.codeplex.com/).NET in my project but I have legacy code and can't do Code First modeling, I use the VS2010 tool to generate my model from the DB.

But it seems that the out of the box entities that the design tool generated can't be used with the repositories in the CommonLibrary, It gives the error:

> Error 1   The type 'RepositoryTest.UserInfo' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'ComLib.Entities.RepositorySql<T>'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'RepositoryTest.UserInfo' to
>   'ComLib.Entities.IEntity'.

Did anyone had this problem also, if so maybe there is a simple solution?

I would like also to know if anyone have a good alternative framework or project that implements repositories that support EF entities.
I am TDDing so I would like to have an implementation of a repository in memory in the same framework, This was the reason I choose this framework in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that `ComLib.Entities.RepositorySql<T>` has a generic constraint, something like

```
public class RepositorySql<T> where T : IEntity
{
    // ...
}
```

This means that your Entity classes have to implement this interface `ComLib.Entities.IEntity` in order to be used as the generic type parameter of the repository. So your class must look like:

```
public class UserInfo : IEntity
{
    // implementation of IEntity
    // look in documentation what you have to implement
    // or hit ctrl-period in Visual Studio on IEntity
    // to get a default implementation

    // your custom code
}
```

Comment: I understand that but I am using automatic code generation and it's a problem to convert the classes to the IEntity implementation, this is why I am looking for help

Comment: @David MZ: Are you using `EntityObject` derived entities? Then you could implement the interface in a custom partial class. If you are using the T4 POCO generator then you could modify the T4 template to derive each entity from `IEntity`.